# Why can't I merge() my domain object without a LockTimeoutException?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, concurrency, transactions

I am creating a CRUD API using hibernate as my persistence layer.

The API takes JSON and serializes it to a POJO.  A management layer then converts the POJO into a new Hibernate Domain object.

This exact same code is run for both `Create` and `Update` - the only difference is that for `Update` I also set the ID field of the hibernate object.

Creating works just fine, but Update fails out with a `org.hibernate.exception.LockTimeoutException`.  After hours of snooping around I'm going to wave the white flag and hope someone can explain all the reasons I'm an idiot.

**ClientManager Code**

```
public class ClientManager {

    private static final ClientDAO clientDAO = new ClientDAO();

    ...

    public Client updateClient(ClientVO inputVO) {

        // Generate a Client from the input
        Client client = ClientManager.generateClient(inputVO);
        client.setClientKey(Integer.parseInt(inputVO.getPersonalId()));
        client.setUpdateDate(new Date());
        client.setUpdateTimestamp(new Date());

        // Update the client
        clientDAO.update(client);

    }

    ...

    public static Client generateClient(ClientVO clientVO) {
        Client client = new Client();

        client.setFirstName(clientVO.getFirstName());
        client.setMiddleName(clientVO.getMiddleName());
        client.setLastName(clientVO.getLastName());

        return client;
    }
}
```

**BaseDAO Code (ClientDAO extends BaseDAO)**

```
public class BaseDAO {
    public Boolean save(Object object) {
        Session session = getSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(object);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    public Boolean update(Object object) {
        Session session = getSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.merge(object);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    public Session getSession() 
    {
        return HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
    }   
}
```

**Entry Point Code**

```
@PUT
@Path("clients/{personalId}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public String updateClient(@PathParam("personalId") String personalId, String data) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ClientVO inputVO = om.readValue(data, ClientVO.class);
    inputVO.setPersonalId(personalId);

    ClientVO outputVO = clientManager.updateClient(inputVO);
    return om.writeValueAsString(outputVO);
}
```

Note that clientKey is the primary key.

The timeout is happening at the point of the `.commit()` in the update() method of BaseDAO.

I'm happy to provide more code (e.g. ClientVO) if useful.

Answer (score 4):

The only way this can happen is that you have two database connections that both attempt to modify the same entity.

If this happens with a single-user, it is because you don't use the same Session for the whole request but instead you create several ones. I would say that you open a Hibernate Session and a transaction in some outer-level and when the *update* method is called you open another Session and a new transaction that conflicts with the outer one that might have already acquired locks on the same entity (because you loaded the entity and change it).

Comment: That is a very helpful line of thought -- and I just went through to tighten my sessions to ensure I `.close()` them appropriately but alas, the issue still stands.  I'll keep digging in case I missed something, and I'm updating the question to show the entry point.

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that I have no wrapping transactions at this point -- is there any chance that Hibernate is doing strange things because I'm manually setting the primary key of a raw domain object rather than "looking up" the object?

Comment: I also used to up update entities by manually setting the entity identifier along with other properties coming from a DTO. This is a database lock that's causing you problems. Are you using some triggers that acquire locks on some other database rows in some other tables?

Comment: No triggers, the schema is pretty simple, defined here: https://github.com/PCNI/OpenHMIS/tree/feature-compass_schema/src/main/resources/db/migration || I'll keep digging and will report back when I know more.  Very good to understand that what I'm doing is not inherently violating something about hibernate.